# Executing a http request with properties from a variable, which comes from another http request

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, asynchronous, xmlhttprequest

My problem is kinda complicated. The situation looks like:

I have a function:

```
private updateWatchlistTable(name) {
  this._watchlistElements = [];
  this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getPoints/' + name)
  .subscribe(res => this._watchlistElements = res.json());
}
```

Which downloads a JSON file from server, which looks like:
`[{"xid":"DP_049908","name":"t10"},{"xid":"DP_928829","name":"t13"},{"xid":"DP_588690","name":"t14"}]`

And stores it inside the:
`private _watchlistElements: Array<WatchlistComponent> = [];`
variable.

**As for now, everything works well.**

And now, I have another function:

```
private getValues() {
 this._watchlistElements.map((v => this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)
 .subscribe(res => this._values = res.json())));
}
```

Which downloads data for every single point `xid` from the `_watchlistElements` variable. The response, which comes for (just in this case) the `"xid": "DP_049908"` point, looks like:

`{"value":"32.339264","ts":1476778297100,"xid":"DP_049908"}`

**What's the problem?**

The problem is that this second function `getValues()` is unable to execute these http calls because basically it can't see  the `xid` property from the `_watchlistElements` variable. I'm not 100% sure, but I think that it's caused by the fact, that these calls are ASYNCHRONOUS. That second function `getValues()` - while executing - doesn't have access to the `_watchlistElements` properties, because the content of this variable is being downloaded from a asynchronous request aswell.

> *If I do it statically, by saving these jsons in separate files - everything works well.*

**How does the error look like?**

> ERROR in [default] C:\Users\src\app\appBody\watchlist\watchlist.component.ts:51:115 Property 'xid' does not exist on type 'WatchlistComponent'.

Any help highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use `return`, `.then()`, to call second function when `Promise` at first function is fulfilled. Use `Promise.all()` at second call to return all promise values returned from `.map()` call to chained `.then()`.

```
private updateWatchlistTable(name) {
  this._watchlistElements = [];
  // note `return`
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getPoints/' + name)
  .subscribe(res => this._watchlistElements = res.json());
}

private getValues() {
 let _this = this;
 // note `return`
 return Promise.all(this._watchlistElements
 .map(v => _this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)
 .subscribe(res => _this._values = res.json())));
}

updateWatchlistTable(name)
.then(getValues)
// do stuff with `result`
.then(result => console.log(result)) 
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: That third function is obligatory? Or it's just an alternative for the first one?

Comment: No. The last `.then()` is not necessary if you access the values at another portion of `javascript`

Comment: `Promise.all()` may not be necessary either if `.map()` is not `Array.prototype.map()` and `.subscribe()` returns a `Promise` object.

Comment: I don't really get the third part of your answer. `updateWatchlistTable(name)
.then(getValues).catch(e => console.log(e)); ` If I just paste it into script, few errors appears. Where should I paste it?

Comment: What are the errors? `updateWatchlistTable(name).then(getValues)` should call `getValues` when `updateWatchlistTable` promise is fulfilled. Does `.subscribe()` return a `Promise`?

Comment: But shouldnt it be inside some functions body or anything? Where should I drop it? `updateWatchlistTable(name).then(getValues)`

Comment: `getValues` is a function. `.then()` accepts and expects a function as a parameter. At `javascript` at Answer `getValues` is passed to `.then()` as a function reference, and is called within `.then()`; e.g., `function getValues(n) {
  console.log(n)
}
Promise.resolve(1).then(getValues)`

Comment: If I just drop it inside the script, the Webstorm returns a warning: `Function implementation is missing or not immediately following the declaration`.

Comment: Have not tried Webstorm. Which function is warning referring to? Not an error, but a warning, yes? Does `.then(() => getValues())` log a warning?

Comment: Yes, a warning.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your good intentions, but it doesn't fix anything. The script still can't see that `xid` property and won't let the rest of the script to work properly. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: Is `this` the same within both functions? Nearly edited this portion of `javascript` earlier, as `this` within `.map()` is probably not the `this` you are expecting? `.map(v => this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/getValue/' + v.xid)`. Was not sure if the `.map()` used is a custom `.map()` or `Array.prototype.map()`? What is `this` within `.subscribe()` function? See updated post